# compact convergence for a series in complex space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, compactness

I need some help with this.
I have to show that the follwing series converges compat.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n :D:= \{z \in \mathbb{C} | Re(z) > 0 \} \to \mathbb{C}, f_n (z):=\frac{1}{z+n^2} $$

I tried to separate $Re$ and $Im$ to apply the Leibniz-test but $Re$ does not converge to $0$. Can someone give me a hint or which rule to apply or a direction to proceed?

Comment: The series already converges normally on $D$.

Comment: so I have to show that this series converges normally and that $D$ is locally compact and that implies that the series converges compact?

Comment: Compact convergence means that the series $\sum f_n\big|_K$ converges uniformly for every compact set $K\subset D$. But the series already converges normally on $D$, hence uniformly on $D$ and thus uniformly on every compact subset of $D$.

Comment: ok I understand. thank you